# Is there a way to set my auto upload settings to a default yes, instead of asking me every time I play a game?

Tags: playstation-plus

Also, is there a way to make the PS3 auto upload all my save data without inserting the game? Basically I want it to upload everything I have saved, and upload every new save automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhat. On the XMB, if you navigate to GAME then SAVED GAME UTILITY (PS3), you'll get a list of games you have saves for. Press triangle to get the side menu to appear and select COPY MULTIPLE. You'll be able to check all your games and then have them copied to online storage. You have only 1024 MB of online storage, so you might not get them all. At least with this method, you don't have to put in every disc and say yes to the pop-up for games you aren't currently playing.